# Does CMake support include directories recursively?

Tags: cmake

Obviously XCode support include directories and all its sub directories. I am wondering if CMake support this mode?

I am currently using include_directores

Comment: please clarify using an example

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to add recursively files**

You have to use the `GLOB_RECURSE` mode from [FILE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:file) for that.

**If you want to recursively add subdirectories**

You can use this convenient macro for instance (taken from [VTK Cmake examples](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake/Examples#Recursively_add_subdirectories_to_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES))

```
MACRO(HEADER_DIRECTORIES return_list)
    FILE(GLOB_RECURSE new_list *.h)
    SET(dir_list "")
    FOREACH(file_path ${new_list})
        GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(dir_path ${file_path} PATH)
        SET(dir_list ${dir_list} ${dir_path})
    ENDFOREACH()
    LIST(REMOVE_DUPLICATES dir_list)
    SET(${return_list} ${dir_list})
ENDMACRO()
```

A remark from the CMake doc (which I personnaly do not follow) :

> We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from
>   your source tree

Comment: how to use it correctly? what I'm doing wrong (I write ';' just to split on lines, really there is no that symbol) : HEADER_DIRECTORIES(MY_INCLUDES); INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${MY_INCLUDES});message("INcludes: " ${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}) - empty output